# Font with black outline in Xorg

Tags: fonts, xorg, outline

Are there any fonts available for Xorg that has an outline, e.g. white text with black outline? I think this would be better for transparent terminals.

Comment: It's my understanding that fonts are monochromatic.  Any kind of outlining functionality would be part of the "font rendering engine" per se, not part of the font.  I don't know of any desktop environment / compositor that does this, but I've never looked.

Comment: @JeffBreadner I see. Well, the question still stands, I guess.